# Java - [Var Type] Cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jpanel

I've been troubling over this error for the last half an hour. `JPanel cannot be resolved to a type` But yet, I've imported `javax.swing.JPanel;`, and I can't see another reason why this is being caused. I've found no help on good or other questions. The interesting thing with the problem though, is it's happening with all variables that are from the swing package. I've tried re-adding the `JRE System Library` (I'm using eclipse), but this has had no help. Here's some of the code I'm using;

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.JSeparator;

public class Workshop {
    private JFrame window = new JFrame("Meejo WorkShop");
    private JLayeredPane lpane = new JLayeredPane();
    private JPanel panelBg = new JPanel();
    private JPanel panelGame = new JPanel();
    private JPanel panelProp = new JPanel();
    private JPanel panelWork = new JPanel();
```

Is an example of the problems. All the variables give the error `[Var Type] Cannot be resolved to a type` over `rivate` and `= ne` Any ideas, why? And if so, how could I fix it? Thanks.

EDIT: The full code is;

```
package mj.workshop;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.JSeparator;

public class Workshop {
    private final JFrame window = new JFrame("Meejo WorkShop");
    private final JLayeredPane lpane = new JLayeredPane();
    private final JPanel panelBg = new JPanel();
    private final JPanel panelGame = new JPanel();
    private final JPanel panelProp = new JPanel();
    private final JPanel panelWork = new JPanel();

    private final JMenuBar windowMenu = new JMenuBar();
    private final JMenu menuFile = new JMenu("File");
    private final JMenu menuEdit = new JMenu("Edit");
    private final JMenu menuHelp = new JMenu("Help");
    // private JMenu menuTest = new JMenu("Test");
    private final JMenuItem menuFileNew = new JMenuItem("New");
    private final JMenuItem menuFileSave = new JMenuItem("Save");
    private final JMenuItem menuFileSaveAs = new JMenuItem("Save As");
    private final JMenuItem menuFileExit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
    private final JMenuItem menuEditOptions = new JMenuItem("Options");
    // private JMenuItem menuEditRedo = new JMenuItem("Redo");
    // private JMenuItem menuEditUndo = new JMenuItem("Undo");
    // private JMenuItem menuEditCopy = new JMenuItem("Copy");
    // private JMenuItem menuEditCut = new JMenuItem("Cut");
    // private JMenuItem menuEditPaste = new JMenuItem("Paste");
    // private JMenuItem menuEditInsert_Comment = new
    // JMenuItem("Insert Comment");
    private final JMenuItem menuHelpSupport = new JMenuItem("Support");
    private final JMenuItem menuHelpAbout = new JMenuItem("About");
    private final JMenuItem menuHelpTips = new JMenuItem("Tips");
    private final JPopupMenu menuHelpTipsPopUp = new JPopupMenu("Tips");
    // private JMenuItem menuTestStart = new JMenuItem("Start");
    // private JMenuItem menuTestPause = new JMenuItem("Pause");
    // private JMenuItem menuTestStop = new JMenuItem("Stop");

    int xSize, ySize;

    public Workshop() {
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        xSize = ((int) tk.getScreenSize().getWidth());
        ySize = ((int) tk.getScreenSize().getHeight());
        window.setSize(xSize, ySize);
        xSize = window.getWidth();
        ySize = window.getHeight();
        Image icon = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("images/icon.png");
        window.setIconImage(icon);
        window.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        window.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(600, 450));

        setUpMenu();

        Thread mainThread = new Thread();
        mainThread.start();

        window.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(xSize, ySize));
        window.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        window.add(lpane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        lpane.setBounds(0, 0, 600, 400);
        panelBg.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        panelBg.setBounds(0, 0, xSize, ySize);
        panelBg.setOpaque(true);
        panelProp.setBackground(new Color(235, 235, 235));
        panelProp.setBounds(0, (int) (Math.round(ySize * 0.20)),
                (int) (Math.round(xSize * 0.175)),
                (int) (Math.round(ySize * 0.80)));
        panelProp.setOpaque(true);
        panelWork.setBackground(new Color(235, 235, 235));
        panelWork.setBounds((int) (Math.round(xSize * 0.825)),
                (int) (Math.round(ySize * 0.20)),
                (int) (Math.round(xSize * 0.175)),
                (int) (Math.round(ySize * 0.80)));
        panelWork.setOpaque(true);
        panelGame.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        panelGame.setBounds((int) (Math.round(xSize * 0.175)),
                (int) (Math.round(ySize * 0.20)),
                (int) (Math.round(xSize * 0.65)),
                (int) (Math.round(ySize * 0.80)));
        panelGame.setOpaque(true);
        lpane.add(panelBg, new Integer(0), 0);
        lpane.add(panelGame, new Integer(1), 0);
        lpane.add(panelProp, new Integer(1), 0);
        lpane.add(panelWork, new Integer(1), 0);
        window.pack();
        window.setVisible(true);

        while (true) {
            windowrefresh();
        }

    }

    public void windowrefresh() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            xSize = window.getWidth();
            ySize = window.getHeight();
            panelProp.setBounds(0, (int) (Math.round(ySize * 0.20)),
                    (int) (Math.round(xSize * 0.175)),
                    (int) (Math.round(ySize * 0.80)));
            panelWork.setBounds((int) (Math.round(xSize * 0.825)),
                    (int) (Math.round(ySize * 0.20)),
                    (int) (Math.round(xSize * 0.175)),
                    (int) (Math.round(ySize * 0.80)));
            panelGame.setBounds((int) (Math.round(xSize * 0.175)),
                    (int) (Math.round(ySize * 0.20)),
                    (int) (Math.round(xSize * 0.65)),
                    (int) (Math.round(ySize * 0.80)));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void setUpMenu() {
        menuFileSave.setEnabled(false);
        menuFileSaveAs.setEnabled(false);
        menuFile.add(menuFileNew);
        menuFile.add(menuFileSave);
        menuFile.add(menuFileSaveAs);
        menuFile.add(new JSeparator());
        menuFile.add(menuFileExit);
        menuEdit.add(menuEditOptions);
        // menuEdit.add(menuEditRedo);
        // menuEdit.add(menuEditUndo);
        // menuEdit.add(menuEditCopy);
        // menuEdit.add(menuEditCut);
        // menuEdit.add(menuEditPaste);
        // menuEdit.add(menuEditInsert_Comment);
        menuHelp.add(menuHelpSupport);
        menuHelp.add(menuHelpAbout);
        menuHelp.add(new JSeparator());
        menuHelp.add(menuHelpTips);
        // windowTest.add(menuTestStart);
        // windowTest.add(menuTestPause);
        // windowTest.add(menuTestStop);
        windowMenu.add(menuFile);
        windowMenu.add(menuEdit);
        windowMenu.add(menuHelp);
        // windowMenu.add(menuTest);
        windowMenu.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        window.setJMenuBar(windowMenu);

        menuHelpTips.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent evt) {
                if (evt.isPopupTrigger()) {
                    menuFileSave.setEnabled(true);
                    menuFileSaveAs.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent evt) {
                if (evt.isPopupTrigger()) {
                    menuFileSave.setEnabled(true);
                    menuFileSaveAs.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you build the application? Maybe this options is disabled. Assure that Project -> Build Automatically is checked. After that, make a Project -> Clean...

Comment: no, they don't need to be public. in eclipse, what libraries show up under project properties? what you have looks fine

Comment: Maybe your Java installation is corrupted or not properly associated with Eclipse

Comment: None of your code looks like it has a problem. Must have to do with your build path and/or eclipse.

Comment: Reimus makes a good point. you need the JDK, not just the JRE. also, depending on your system, you may need to add environment variables and paths to your system settings

Comment: @JeffHawthorne You don't need the JDK, only JRE is enough to use Eclipse.

Comment: I've already re-downloaded eclipse, and it's got the exact same problems. And yes, I got a JDK. @DanielPereira, Project -> Build Automatically doesn't exist for me, and cleaning the project creates no difference other than changing all the variables to `private final`

Comment: Right click in your project, Properties -> Java Compiler. Is the checkbox "Enable project specific settings" enabled? If yes, you can either disabled it or go to Java Build Path and make sure that the JRE is the same that you have installed.

Comment: No, it wasn't enabled. Enabling it, makes no difference, and yes, the JRE is the same version I have installed.

Comment: Can you post the full code?

Comment: Yes, mind it's very inefficient and messy. Adding it on to the post.

Comment: This might be an encoding problem with your source files if it's literally reporting `rivate` and `ne` as tokens.

Comment: Did you try to create a new java project? Do you see in the Package Explorer "JRE System Library?"

Comment: @Brian, thanks for saying that, I had to change encoding UTF-8, re-do the imports, and it was fine. Again, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in Brian's comment, it was just an encoding problem. Changing to UTF-8 fixes all errors after re-doing all the imports.